# What is this TSQL V() method/syntax/function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have just come across this syntax for defining an inline view...

```
SELECT myAlias, myAlias1 FROM ( SELECT myCol, myCol1 FROM myTable ) V( myAlias, myAlias1)
```

I can see what the V is doing, but what is this called and where is it documented? And why would I ever want to do this when I can just define the aliases inside the inline view?

Googling seems not to be working because V is not a word!

Comment: A similar concept is the [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). I suggest the use of better alias names - single characters are not intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`V` is just another alias - it's the alias for the whole subquery, not for an individual column.

See the *derived table* line from the [syntax for FROM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax):

> ```
>    | derived_table [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]
> ```

`V` is the `table_alias`.

> when I can just define the aliases inside the inline view

Yes, you often can. But sometimes you're building a complex query with lots of nesting in the individual column expressions, and it's easier to place all of the names (the `table_alias` and `column_alias`es) that will be exposed to the remaining parts of the query in one place.

Comment: I have **never** seen column aliases used like that before on a derived table. That is really neat!